# Volume applet in the tray has gone. How can I get it back?

Tags: sound, indicator-sound

Ok, so I installed KDE on my Ubuntu 11.04 laptop. It worked ok, but I wanted to change back, and free up the space, so (having kept unity etc. installed), just rebooted into what GDM calls "Ubuntu". So far so good.

I then wanted to rid myself of all KDE packages, so di sudo apt-get remove kde* . I realise this was fairly silly.

Now I've lost my sound applet in the system tray. It's more annoying than anything else, but I've got used to the play/pause functionality, so it'd be nice to get it back. Thanks in advance for whatever help you may be able to give!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you issue a command similar to the following, do you see indicator-sound-service?

```
ps ax | grep 'indicator'
```

[image]

In case the package was inadvertently removed, try the following:

[image: Install via the software center]

or

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound
```

Comment: Yes! reinstalling it helped. Must have uninstalled it by accident when I was removing KDE. Thanks for the (super-quick) help!

Comment: Glad to hear (read) that everything worked out for you with minimum fuss.

Answer (score 5):

Does this work?

`sudo apt-get install indicator-sound`

Answer (score 2):

in synaptic search for "sound indicator" and make sure it is installed!
then you might have to re login.